# error phpunit executable not found

Tags: windows-7, kubuntu, phpunit, composer

In an API project, we have composer.json set to the following:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.7.*"
    },
     "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "1.5.*"
    }
}
```

And, upon the first `composer install` everything was fine. Phpunit worked when invoked with `vendor/bin/phpunit`. My work machine is a Windows 7 OS, however we use git with this project, and when I work on this from another machine (Kubuntu 14.04), after doing `git pull`,  I can no longer run unit tests with `vendor/bin/phpunit` - it fails with error that it cannot find vendor/bin/phpunit.

On the linux machine, I deleted the non-functioning executable vendor/bin/phpunit, and removed vendor/phpunit folder, and had composer replace it via `composer update`.  At that point, I'm able to run unit tests again as before. However this doesn't work as seamlessly on Windows 7. It's trickier.

My question is: Am I doing something wrong by tracking the files through github and then working on various operating systems?  Would I avoid this error if I only kept track of `composer.json` and keep the contents of `vendor/phpunit/phpunit` directory untracked (and let the files stay with their specific OS)?  Thanks, Adam.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of Composer is that you just have to have an empty(!) `vendor` directory in your repo but track `composer.json` (requirements) and `composer.lock` (last tested specific versions) and run `composer install` after checkout on a new development machine.

(NB. `composer install` will install the specific versions according to the `composer.lock` file. `composer update` will install whatever latest version matches the requirements defined in the `composer.json`.)

Composer should then download the appropriate binary for your system and put it into the `vendor/bin/` directory.

Comment: I am just confused since it all works fine, then I push tests to the remote repository.  For some reason the vendor folder itself gets LOTS of modifications, that (I am guessing) upon a git pull from other machine the compatibility and path-finding of the executable vendor/bin/php go out of whack.

Comment: I have done the composer install after the checkout on the new development machine. What I'm not understanding is just 'how' git "thinks" all these files have been modified (from the vendor folder) when I didn't touch em.  Of course doing a pull down of files specific to a winders machine might confuse a different machine altogether, which is why the thought of simply "not tracking" these files came to mind. Track composer.json, but do not bother with tracking the files that composer may pull down.